# How to Simplify Different but Similar Functions?

Tags: javascript

absolute newbie here. I need help with simplifying my code. I want to create many more similar functions as shown below. Is there a simpler way where I can code without having to manually type in the same function every time I want to add a new function?

```
function toggleItem1() {

    var myItem1 = document.getElementById('item1Image');
    var displaySetting = myItem1.style.display;
    var item1Button = document.getElementById('item1Button');

    if (displaySetting == 'block') {
      myItem1.style.display = 'none';
      item1Button.innerHTML = 'Show item';
    } else {

      myItem1.style.display = 'block';
      item1Button.innerHTML = 'Hide item';
    }
  }


function toggleItem2() {

    var myItem2 = document.getElementById('item2Image');
    var displaySetting = myItem2.style.display;
    var item2Button = document.getElementById('item2Button');

    if (displaySetting == 'block') {
      myItem2.style.display = 'none';
      item2Button.innerHTML = 'Show item';
    } else {

      myItem2.style.display = 'block';
      item2Button.innerHTML = 'Hide item';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Mini-review: `Item1` and`Item2` are not very descriptive identifiers; they should be made more meaningful.

Comment: @TobySpeight The code is obvious enough to provide sufficient context.

Comment: @konjin, it includes nothing at all to indicate its purpose; it doesn't even include a document that contains `item1Image`, `item1Button`, `item2Image` and `item2Button`.

Comment: (Numbering *named things* is a *code smell*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar but different functions can be merged by using parameters.

```
function toggleItem(itemId, buttonId) {

    var item = document.getElementById(itemId);
    var displaySetting = item.style.display;
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);

    if (displaySetting == 'block') {
      item.style.display = 'none';
      button.innerHTML = 'Show item';
    } else {

      item.style.display = 'block';
      button.innerHTML = 'Hide item';
    }
  }

// usage
toggleItem('item1image', 'item1button')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it! :D